# Variable substitution in Databricks with Backtics?

Tags: sql, databricks

I am having trouble to sustitute variable in a simlpe %sql script in databricks

```
%sql
SET container = 'dev';
SELECT *
FROM delta.`dbfs:/mnt/${container}/stage/temp/data` AS hv;
```

I would like the following result:

```
SELECT *
FROM delta.`dbfs:/mnt/dev/stage/temp/data` AS hv;
```